# How to modify the Login view in inherited class in django?

Tags: django, django-views

I want to handle "confirm form resubmission" pop ups, when the user refresh the login page with incorrect data.

I'm using a class named: UserLogin inherited from LoginView('django built-in'), I know that I need to write a method in my own class to handle this issue, and I did it with HttpRespone for my Registration view. who can I solve it for my Login View?

my urls.py:

```
path('login/', UserLogin.as_view(template_name='userLogin/login.html'), name='login')
```

in my views:

```
class UserLogin(LoginView):
    def refresh_page(self):
        pass
        return HttpResponse('login/')
```

I don't know How to fill my refresh_page method. besides, I tried :

```
class UserLogin(LoginView):
    def refresh_page(self):
        print('hello')
```

and I noticed that the method doesn't called at all! because it didn't print "hello" on my console

Comment: can you also post some code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: @SammyJ  I edited my post

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it on different ways, one of them, just send post data to your view where you can handle user action and react to it. For example, like this:

```
class UserLogin(LoginView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.data.get('refresh'):
            self.refresh_page()
        return super().post(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    def refresh_page(self):

        return HttpResponse('login/')
```